# animate SVG line

Tags: css, svg, animate.css, svg-animate

This the code I've created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="466.797,219.464 466.797,456.751 39.678,456.751 
    39.678,40.932 466.797,40.932 466.797,219.464" class="animateline"/>


<style>.animateline{stroke-dasharray:400 20;stroke-dashoffset:300;animation:animatelinedraw 10000ms ease-in-out infinite forwards;}@keyframes animatelinedraw{100%{stroke-dashoffset:0;}}@keyframes MOdKuuJM_fade{0%{stroke-opacity:1;}94.44444444444444%{stroke-opacity:1;}100%{stroke-opacity:0;stroke-dashoffset:}}</style>


</svg>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to redraw the line and close the gaps you see in an animated way. Then re open the gaps and have it on a loop doing the same thing again.

Right now the gaps stay always open and the loops looks weird every time as it's not a continuous "drawing" movement. I don't know much from SVG so even though I've search all over the web I couldn't find an answer to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to close the gaps you will need to animate the `stroke-dasharray` too

```
@keyframes animatelinedraw{
  50%{stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-dasharray:400 0;}
}
```

The second value of the the `stroke-dasharray` represent the width of the gaps, 0 in this case.

See a working example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">

 <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
       .animateline{
        stroke-dasharray:400 20;
        stroke-dashoffset:300;
        animation:animatelinedraw 10000ms ease-in-out infinite forwards;
        }

        @keyframes animatelinedraw{
        50%{stroke-dashoffset:0;
            stroke-dasharray:400 0;
            }
        }

        ]]> 
  </style>

<polyline fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="466.797,219.464 466.797,456.751 39.678,456.751 
    39.678,40.932 466.797,40.932 466.797,219.464" class="animateline"/>


</svg>
```